# Make form submit custom HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to have an icon as the submit button for my form. Something like:

```
<%= form.submit do %>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-2x"></i>
<% end %>
```

Is having custom html as a form submit possible, if so what is the syntax?

Comment: No, the submit helper always creates an input element of type submit, it doesnt accept blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html button tag:

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-2x"></i></button>`

That's it!

Comment: Why not using the Rails helpers? f.button